# How to wrap anchor link around shape in css

Tags: css

I have a question about wrapping anchors around a menu shape in CSS. This is the menu in question:

[image: This is what I've got]

A menu consisting of circles, and of course anchor elements wrapped around them in squares (as default.)

[image: This is how they are made in HTML]

The circles are made up like this:

```
height: 3rem;
width: 3rem;
border-radius: 50%;
margin: 0 3rem !important;
display: inline-block !important;
cursor: pointer;
background-color: #005929;
```

How would I do to make the anchor tag wrap around the shape of the list item and not just the square / `li`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the CSS you have to the link itself, not to the container. Please see example below.

```css
a {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 3rem !important;
  display: inline-block !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

ul {
list-style: none;
display: flex;
width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="red"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="blue"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="yellow"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#" class="green"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```